# Are Anti DDoS server farms really effective?

Tags: ddos, web-hosting

I'm looking to host a web app in a datacenter and I'm considering a few options. All of them seem reputable and claim to offer Anti-DDoS protection.

If just about every hosting provider is offering Anti-DDoS protection, does that mean that a) DDoS attacks are less of a threat because Anti-DDoS technology has caught up or that b) many of these claims are not as solid as advertised and if so, how can I tell if a web hosting company is really DDoS protected?

Thanks.

Comment: While there are is DDOS protection there is no such thing as 100% DDOS protection. Ask the specific hosting provider for details of what strength and type of DDOS against your host they are willing to take and at which point they will simply cut you off so that the other customers are not too much affected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience, there is no such thing as 100% DDoS protection. The largest DDoS cyber-attacks ever recorded have reached and exceed 1Tbps. Even if some company claims that they can protect you against such an attack, that would be a false statement.  The Internet of Things is perhaps the best mean an attacker can use since the level of security on those devices is extremely low. Therefore, the attackers have all the means to launch extremely large DDoS attacks nowadays.

In principle, the quality of the DDoS protection services you get, depends heavily on how much money you are willing to spend. Most of the ISPs that offer Internet Breakouts to web hosting companies, bundle some sort of DDoS protection. Some Web hosting companies might not choose to do the “washing” of the traffic on the cloud though, and might prefer on-premise devices (for example there are basic DDoS mechanisms on some firewalls or some load balancers).

If you are concerned about having good DDoS protection, I would suggest you to talk to the Web Hosting companies you are interested in, get answers in writing on what kind of DDoS protection they are using and evaluate which one is the best. I would strongly suggest picking a company that has a hybrid DDoS protection environment, meaning that they do traffic “washing” on the cloud first using some 3rd party vendor, and at the same time they also have a second layer of protection using on-premise devices which also acts as a detection mechanism. In general, I would stick with a company that uses well-known vendors in the DDoS protection field such as Incapsula, Arbor, CloudFlare, F5 Networks (ASM Module on Load Balancers), etc.